# Sending messages using sockets on local host

Tags: java, sockets, networking, io

I am working on messaging over sockets on my local machine. I am trying to message myself, which is emulating me messaging over the internet. Anyhow, I had gotten a bind exception earlier but it seems I may have gotten past that. Now I am getting the :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at class2.main(class2.java:10)
```

How do I get this connection to work and my messages to pass. Here are the two classes in my program:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class IPMessenger {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        ServerSocket SC = new ServerSocket(4800);
        Socket socket = SC.accept();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println(in.readDouble());
        System.out.println("hi");
    //  out.writeChars("hello");
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class class2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
        Socket sock = new Socket("localhost",4800);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        out.writeDouble(5);
       //System.out.println(in.readChar());
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your exception with stack trace.

Comment: Which process you start **first**?

Comment: I am unsure. I did not know I could start one before the other.

Comment: You have 2 public classes with `main()` method.  So you can run them in any order you like.

Comment: Well they both start at the exact same time I believe.

Comment: OK. Describe your actions step-by-step.  While it's possible to start the two processes virtually simultaneously, it's not a trivial task.

Comment: @user3602515 Clearly you're mistaken. Clearly the client is being started first.

Comment: In Eclipse, I click run and both classes are checked. So they both run I believe.

Comment: @user3602515 Certainly they do, but not simultaneously. Adjust your procedure.

Comment: Wow I think that when I run them both at the same time there is an error. For the first time ever I just realized I could run one class and run the other after.

Comment: It is working now. It is still kinda confusing but it does work not. I just learned to to start classes separately, but I do not know how exactly I had errors at first. I Think I started the client first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Your server isn't running when you run the client.

Comment: How do I start one before I start the other?

Comment: Same way you start the other. Start the server, then the client. What's the problem?